# Лишние пропуски между элементами меню

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, меню

[image: Скрин]

На картинке видно, что при наведении между элементами меню есть небольшой пробел. Вопрос -как его убрать. Код прилагается.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('li').click(function() {
      $("li.active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass('active');
})
});
```

```css
* {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

#menu {
 width:100%;
 height: auto;
 background: #313A3F;
}

header {
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 background: #2794CF;
 color:  white;
 padding: 40px;
 padding-left: 100px;
}

#company_name {
 font-size: 45px;
 font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
}

#subtitle {
 font-size: 45px;
 position:absolute;
 left:800px;
 top:48px;
 font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive;
}

#menu_ul {
 /*list-style-type: none;*/
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
 color:white;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #2794CF;
 font-size: 26px;
 margin-bottom:30px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
 font-variant: small-caps;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu_ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 width:auto;
 padding:30px;
 border-left: 1px solid black;
 transition:0.3s ease;
}

#menu_ul li:first-child {
 border-left: none;
}

li.active {
 background: #2794CF;
 border-bottom: 10px #313A3F solid;
}

#menu_ul li:not(.active):hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background: black;
 transition:0.2s ease;
 height:auto;
 border-bottom: 10px solid white;
}

#menu_ul li:not(.active):not(:first-child):hover + li, #menu_ul li:not(.active):not(:first-child):hover, #menu_ul li.active + li, #menu_ul li.active {
 border-left:transparent 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Генератор слоганов - TaglineDraft</title>
  <link href="main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="favicon.ico" type="image/png" rel="shortcut icon">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marck+Script&subset=cyrillic,latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>   
  <script src="index.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <header><font id="company_name">TaglineDraft</font><span id="subtitle" align="right">Бесплатный сервис для Ваших идей</span></header>
  <div id="menu">
   <ul id="menu_ul">
    <li class="active">генератор слоганов</li>
    <li>аббревиатуры</li>
    <li>генератор паролей</li>
    <li>генератор брендов</li>
    <li>лучшее</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="slogan_generator">
  </div>
  <div id="abbr">
  </div>
  <div id="pass_generator">
  </div>
  <div id="brand_generator">
  </div>
  <div id="the_best">
  </div>
  <!--<footer><font id="about"><name>TaglineDraft</name> - это сервис, позволяющий Вам создавать лозунги и слоганы на любую тематику. Также Вы можете сгенерировать безопасный пароль для Вашего аккаунта, интересное, звучное название для Вашей компании и расшифровывать аббреавитуры! Присоединяйтесь к нам)</font></footer> -->
 </body>
</html
```

Comment: http://css-live.ru/articles/zagadochnye-otstupy-mezhdu-inlajn-blokami.html

Comment: @soledar10, спасибо, очень помогло) напишите как ответ, поставлю голос)

Comment: Возникла еще такая проблема - при переключении на первый элемент на долю секунды возникает белая левая рамка, потом исчезает. Есть способы исправить?

Comment: @Niklex для начала надо понять, что за рамка) посмотрите через отладчик, например, какой стиль применяется, и поймёте, что надо исправлять. как вариант - может появляться точечный пунктир, например, к этому приводит `outline` у активного елемента. либо вслепую "обнулите" `border` и `outline` для всех состояний )))

Comment: @lexxl, спасибо, учту)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609992/Отступы-между-элементами-с-inline-block/610041#610041

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, в таких случаях лучше закомментировать перенос строки при формировании списка: `... </li><!--  --><li> ...`. Читаемость сохраняется, код не изменяется.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('li').click(function() {
      $("li.active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass('active');
})
});
```

```css
* {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

#menu {
 width:100%;
 height: auto;
 background: #313A3F;
}

header {
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 background: #2794CF;
 color:  white;
 padding: 40px;
 padding-left: 100px;
}

#company_name {
 font-size: 45px;
 font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
}

#subtitle {
 font-size: 45px;
 position:absolute;
 left:800px;
 top:48px;
 font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive;
}

#menu_ul {
 /*list-style-type: none;*/
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
 color:white;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #2794CF;
 font-size: 26px;
 margin-bottom:30px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
 font-variant: small-caps;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu_ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 width:auto;
 padding:30px;
 border-left: 1px solid black;
 transition:0.3s ease;
}

#menu_ul li:first-child {
 border-left: none;
}

li.active {
 background: #2794CF;
 border-bottom: 10px #313A3F solid;
}

#menu_ul li:not(.active):hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background: black;
 transition:0.2s ease;
 height:auto;
 border-bottom: 10px solid white;
}

#menu_ul li:not(.active):not(:first-child):hover + li, #menu_ul li:not(.active):not(:first-child):hover, #menu_ul li.active + li, #menu_ul li.active {
 border-left:transparent 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Генератор слоганов - TaglineDraft</title>
  <link href="main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="favicon.ico" type="image/png" rel="shortcut icon">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marck+Script&subset=cyrillic,latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>   
  <script src="index.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <header><font id="company_name">TaglineDraft</font><span id="subtitle" align="right">Бесплатный сервис для Ваших идей</span></header>
  <div id="menu">
   <ul id="menu_ul">
    <li class="active">генератор слоганов</li><!--
    --><li>аббревиатуры</li><!--
    --><li>генератор паролей</li><!--
    --><li>генератор брендов</li><!--
    --><li>лучшее</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="slogan_generator">
  </div>
  <div id="abbr">
  </div>
  <div id="pass_generator">
  </div>
  <div id="brand_generator">
  </div>
  <div id="the_best">
  </div>
  <!--<footer><font id="about"><name>TaglineDraft</name> - это сервис, позволяющий Вам создавать лозунги и слоганы на любую тематику. Также Вы можете сгенерировать безопасный пароль для Вашего аккаунта, интересное, звучное название для Вашей компании и расшифровывать аббреавитуры! Присоединяйтесь к нам)</font></footer> -->
 </body>
</html
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно изменить в menu_ul добавить:

```
list-style-type: none;
```

А в #menu_ul li

```
display: block; float:left;
```